# Enlarge ImageView to cell size in Dynamic Collection view prototype cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionview, ios-universal-app

I have created a UI collection View controller on which i have a cell with an Image view placed inside. I have 14 cells made dynamically. The collection view cell size gets larger when on iPad. When trying to increase the image size to match the cell size of an iPad, The images stay the same size and are placed in the upper left hand corner of the cell.

Due to there only being one cell, the x and y coordinates are coming back the same for each cell. Because of this i am unable to enlarge the cell using this code.

```
   ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
```

Any ides?

Comment: What about auto layout?

Comment: Sorted. Perfect. Thanks, was getting a bit frustrated!

Comment: Nice to hear that, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment on the original question, it can be solved using Auto Layouts in the storyboard. This is done by adding constraints so that the image fills the cell view.